# how to show validation error when user enter invalid date format on button click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

is there any way to show validation error message or border become red when user enter invalid date format?.In my demo app there two input field in which I am showing date like this "16-jun-1989" .Now user edit this field only in this format (that is valide) if user enter invalid format **I want to show error message on button click or border become red on button click** 
here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/xoTH3uJZSVx0W78rwhMt?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['angularMoment']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope ,moment) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  console.log(moment)
  var d = new Date(613938600000);
  $scope.c = {
   ab: {
      name:'abc'
    },
   date: {
      name: moment(d).format('DD-MMM-YYYY')
    }
    };

    $scope.onclick =function(){
        console.log($scope.c)
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using moment already, check if the date is valid with:

```
moment($scope.c.date.name).isValid()
```

A working example [here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/YPOoazhh7S7I3nfbiyor?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Though this already has answer. You might also be interested in ensuring the date is specified exactly how you want it. The validation in the accepted answer is not strict:
This should fix that:

```
$scope.onclick = function() {
    if (!moment($scope.c.date.name, 'DD-MMM-YYYY').isValid()) {
      alert('Date must be in the format 02-Nov-2018');
    } else {
      alert('All good');
    }
}
```

The second argument to the `moment` function ensures this strictness.